# How can I send values to the dropdown cell editor?

Tags: ag-grid

I have drop down cell editor and I need to give it values.

How can I pass cell editor parameters to my `agRichSelectCellEditor`?

```
cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Portuguese', '(other)']
}
```

I recommend checking ag-grid's [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php) before asking questions.